# Java - Struts 2: result 'null' not found

Tags: java, struts2

I'm getting a 404 on an action and the message:

result 'null' not found

The mapping for the action is:

```
<action name="startSubmission" class="startSubmissionAction">
    <result type="redirectAction">
        <param name="actionName">uploadFile</param>
    </result>
    <result name="error">/jsp/main/bip/submssionError.jsp</result>
</action>
```

I've tried various combinations - being more explicit - nothing works, latest version:

```
<action name="startSubmission" class="startSubmissionAction" method="execute">
    <result name="success" type="redirectAction">
        <param name="actionName">uploadFile</param>
    </result>
    <result name="error">/jsp/main/bip/submssionError.jsp</result>
</action>
```

I've added a debug line in the action and it looks like it doesn't even get called - as nothing gets output.

I upped the debugging on the logs and got:

```
[DEBUG] 2014-08-11 15:49:55,852 com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.InstantiatingNullHandler - Entering nullPropertyValue [target=[com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultTextProvider@7a754707], property=struts]
[DEBUG] 2014-08-11 15:49:55,853 com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.InstantiatingNullHandler - Entering nullPropertyValue [target=[com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultTextProvider@7a754707], property=struts]
[DEBUG] 2014-08-11 15:49:55,853 com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy - Creating an DefaultActionProxy for namespace [/] and action name [startSubmission]
[DEBUG] 2014-08-11 15:49:55,853 com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor - intercept '//startSubmission' {
[DEBUG] 2014-08-11 15:49:55,853 com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor - applied invocation context locale=en_GB
[DEBUG] 2014-08-11 15:49:55,853 com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor - before Locale=en_GB
[DEBUG] 2014-08-11 15:49:55,854 com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.InstantiatingNullHandler - Entering nullPropertyValue [target=[rang.ui.actions.submission.StartSubmissionAction@35d2bd5f, com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultTextProvider@7a754707], property=struts]
[DEBUG] 2014-08-11 15:49:55,871 org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor - Bypassing //startSubmission
[DEBUG] 2014-08-11 15:49:55,871 com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor - Setting static parameters {}
[DEBUG] 2014-08-11 15:49:55,871 com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor - Setting params NONE
[DEBUG] 2014-08-11 15:49:55,871 com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor - Setting params serviceUserNumber => [ 123456 ] submissionType => [ LIVE ] 
[DEBUG] 2014-08-11 15:49:55,871 com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter - Retrieving convert for class [class rang.ui.actions.submission.StartSubmissionAction] and property [serviceUserNumber]
[DEBUG] 2014-08-11 15:49:55,995 com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter - Converter is null for property [serviceUserNumber]. Mapping size [0]:
[DEBUG] 2014-08-11 15:49:55,995 com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter - field-level type converter for property [serviceUserNumber] = none found
[DEBUG] 2014-08-11 15:49:55,995 com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter - global-level type converter for property [serviceUserNumber] = none found
[DEBUG] 2014-08-11 15:49:55,995 com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter - falling back to default type converter [com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkBasicConverter@44158e17]
[DEBUG] 2014-08-11 15:49:55,995 com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter - Retrieving convert for class [class rang.ui.actions.submission.StartSubmissionAction] and property [submissionType]
[DEBUG] 2014-08-11 15:49:55,996 com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter - field-level type converter for property [submissionType] = none found
[DEBUG] 2014-08-11 15:49:55,996 com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter - global-level type converter for property [submissionType] = none found
[DEBUG] 2014-08-11 15:49:55,996 com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter - falling back to default type converter [com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkBasicConverter@44158e17]
[DEBUG] 2014-08-11 15:49:55,996 org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor - Validating //startSubmission with method execute.
[DEBUG] 2014-08-11 15:49:56,251 com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor - Invoking validate() on action rang.ui.actions.submission.StartSubmissionAction@35d2bd5f
[DEBUG] 2014-08-11 15:49:56,251 com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrefixMethodInvocationUtil - cannot find method [validateExecute] in action [rang.ui.actions.submission.StartSubmissionAction@35d2bd5f]
[DEBUG] 2014-08-11 15:49:56,251 com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrefixMethodInvocationUtil - cannot find method [validateDoExecute] in action [rang.ui.actions.submission.StartSubmissionAction@35d2bd5f]
[DEBUG] 2014-08-11 15:49:56,252 com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation - Executing action method = null
[DEBUG] 2014-08-11 15:49:56,342 org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletDispatcherResult - Forwarding to location null
```

Code for action:

```
     public String execute() throws Exception {

        if (!StringUtils.isNumeric(serviceUserNumber)||serviceUserNumber.length()!=6) {
            super.addActionError("servce user number must be 6 numeric characters only!");
            return ERROR;
        }

        logger.debug("submission object created for SUN: " + this.serviceUserNumber + " submission type: " + this.submissionType);

        return SUCCESS;
    }
```

Spring config:

```
<bean id="startSubmissionAction" class="rang.ui.actions.submission.StartSubmissionAction">
</bean>
```

The upload file action:

```
<action name="uploadFile" class="uploadFileAction">
    <result>/jsp/main/bip/uploadFile.jsp</result>
    <result name="error">/jsp/main/bip/submssionError.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Other actions in this project work fine.  The action is Spring mapped and that is all OK.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do your other action classes inherit from a base class that this class does not, by any chance? Do other methods in the StartSubmissionAction class work?

Comment: All my classes extend a base class to force them to implement execute and also get some helpers.  They all work.  No other methods in StartSubmissionAction.

Comment: You should probably also include the Spring config. It knows it's trying to run the `execute` method because the logs know to try `validateExecute()` etc. Unrelated, but `<result type="redirectAction">uploadFile</result>` is sufficient.

Comment: Try to add `input` result. Also add stacktrace to your question.

Comment: I don't get a stack trace - just the log above if I switch to debug.  Will try adding input now.

Comment: Added <result name="input">/jsp/main/bip/submssionError.jsp</result> - no change.

Comment: Have you seen this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-1933?

Comment: @AleksandrM I'm running a later version and not using a security policy.  Just plain Tomcat.  I will try it in another version of Tomcat though.

Comment: Show your `uploadFile` action. Have you tried to create `redirectAction` result in some other action?

Comment: Also your action bean should be in `prototype` scope.

Comment: @AleksandrM Upload is fine - I'll post later.  It doesn't get to calling this.

Comment: @AleksandrM session beans

Comment: What do you mean *session beans*? As I told you actions should be in `prototype` scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cracked it

An exception gets thrown in the action.

The real culprit is that I had an exception handler defined and it was broken.

Comment: NPE - it's not handling runtime exceptions.  I've tried forcing a few  - like array index out of range - and they all cause the same behaviour.